# Should I put yeast in sweet bread?

Tags: baking, bread, yeast

Do you put yeast in sweet bread? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of sweet bread are you thinking of?

Comment: BTW, I think “bumbum” is a cute name!

Answer (score 2):

What kind of sweet bread? If it’s a “quick” bread, like banana-nut bread, no yeast. The leavening is done chemically by baking powder or baking soda. If you’re referring to enriched breads, like brioche or *pain au lait*, you won’t get a rise unless you add yeast! About a half teaspoon per cup of flour. Less if you’re using a preferment or a cold rise.